Extract Polygon from IFME Face with donut from ifc file
I have a ifc file data source which I read with FME and write it to a PostGIS database.
I read the geometry and use a SurfaceFootprintReplacer to get a polygon from the IFME Faces.
Among other shapes, there is a feature like this one which includes a donut.

When I use the SurfaceFootprintReplacer in FME 2020, the hole is filled which is not what I want. Do you have any idea how I could get a polygon to write to PostGIS with the donut?

I don't have your ifc file but used the screenshot you provided.
If you get the ifc to raster you can do the same.
rastertopolygoncoercer.transformer calculate the areas (to remove the box of the image extent) then wrote the polygons to postgres
see
https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME-Form-Documentation/FME-Transformers/Transformers/rastertopolygoncoercer.htm
No projection used (but can be if that info was available).\
FME 2024.2 (Form) used
QGIS 3.40 (RC) used
Postgres 15 +postgis


Thank you. I was successful with this solution using GeometryCoercer: https://community.safe.com/transformers-9/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-surface-to-3d-pts-lines-or-polygons-8232
